# Is there a way to see free mem history on redhat?

Tags: redhat, unix

Is there a built-in way of checking free mem history or any other performance stat on redhat 6.5--e.g., the past hour, days, weeks etc..

On other systems, I have previously used orca which creates logs of performance stats.

If there is no built-in, is there a recommended way of doing it.

Comment: Such performance history recording isn't considered a requirement for base OS, therefore just a few or maybe no OS has that kind of system built-in. Also, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Tero. I was not asking for a product recommendation. I asked if there was a recommended way of doing it for redhat.

Comment: The recommended way is to use a monitoring software for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one that is always there. Such packages are in the default repos for engineers to set up, such as [sar](/questions/tagged/sar), but are not installed in a default installation.

Answer (score 3):

```
yum install sysstat
```

This will add sar,sadf,sa1,sa2 utilities and default cron.

```
[root@node-2 cron.d]# pwd
/etc/cron.d
[root@node-2 cron.d]# cat sysstat
# Run system activity accounting tool every 10 minutes
*/10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1
# 0 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 600 6 &
# Generate a daily summary of process accounting at 23:53
53 23 * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

By default sa1 will run every 10 minutes and will collect system performance data.

Once you have sar - you can analyze historical system performance like this.

```
Example 1. RAM stats for day 27 of the current month

sadf -d /var/log/sa/sa27 -t -- -r


Example 2. CPU stats for day 27 of the current month

sadf -d /var/log/sa/sa27 -t -- -u

Example 3. IO stats

sadf -d /var/log/sa/sa27 -t -- -b
```

Comment: needless to say - you won't be able to go and analyze performance data prior to date sysstat package was installed. Once it's installed - it starts to collect perf data.